# Bluefish not running as root

Tags: root, bluefish

I was working on a file with the name `login.html` in bluefish opened as root, and I decided to rename it. So I closed bluefish (but without closing the file in bluefish) and renamed the file. When I tried to open bluefish again it gave me this error.

```
error reading list 1 Error opening file: No such file or directory

** (bluefish:24717): WARNING **: no configfile rcfile-2.0, try to convert config files from older versions

config file migration error 1:Error opening file: No such file or directoryerror reading list 1 Error opening file: No such file or directory

(bluefish:24717): GLib-ERROR **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.40.0/./glib/gmem.c:103: failed to allocate 18446744073666193602 bytes
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I can still open bluefish normally (without root).

**UPDATE**

Even reinstalling bluefish did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question on [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2236041). Again, a big thanks to grahammechanical for solving my problem. The solution:

Delete the .bluefish folder from your root directory (since the problem occurred while I had root privileges):

```
sudo rm -r /root/.bluefish
```

Or, if you want to do it with the file manager,

1. type `sudo nautilus` in your terminal
2. press Ctrl + H (to show all hidden files/folders)
3. delete the .bluefish folder

Answer (score 0):

My blufish editor got fixed after doing below:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list 
add below lines: 
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/klaus-vormweg/bluefish/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/klaus-vormweg/bluefish/ubuntu trusty main
```

NOTE: trusty in the above lines is for Ubuntu 14.04 version, yours might be different

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties 
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

NOTE: `8938CE95D36FE61D` in the below line is what I got in my error

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 8938CE95D36FE61D 
gpg --export --armor 8938CE95D36FE61D  | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```